# Automated Test framework for mobile apps (BDD)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

What is automated test framework and  BDD(Behavior-Driven Development) for mobile apps?

How can i develop my own Automated Framework for Xamarin.IOS mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create your own framework - all the hard work has been done for you using UITest and SpecFlow.

**Automation Test:**

Xamarin already have an automation framework that works on iOS and Android apps called UITest.  You write your tests using C# with NUnit (but only up to 2.6.4, NUnit 3 is not yet supported) as the test framework and can interact with your app directly, query the visual tree, enter text, tap buttons, read off values, check what controls are visible and even access backdoors (code in your app for text purposes) or invoke methods on the classes (useful for checking values not in the visual tree).  Once you have your UI tests you can run them on simulators, physical devices or if you are feeling rich enough on their Test Cloud - thousands of physical devices in the cloud.

You can read more on this on their developer site:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/intro-to-uitest/

**BDD**

Once you are using UITest it's really easy to start with BDD using SpecFlow.  There's a Visual Studio extension and a Xamarin Studio add-in to enable this.  Essentially you write your BDD scenarios and behind the scenes NUnit tests are created.  As it's NUnit you can easily use UITest so that your scenarios automate things happening in your app.

You can read more on SpecFlow at http://www.specflow.org

**Screen Object Pattern**

To make your tests easier to write I highly recommend reading up on the screen object pattern (a good guide from Greg Shackles is here: http://gregshackles.com/testing-xamarin-apps-screen-object-pattern/). This pattern allows you to abstract each screen out so if the UI changes you only need to update the screen definition class. You can then write a steps class containing the BDD steps for each screen referencing the screen class, and for your scenarios use these steps.

**More resources**

If you like podcasts I'd highly recommend the recent Gone Mobile episode (hosted by the aforementioned Greg Shackles!) where they discussed this: http://gonemobile.io/blog/e0035.mobile.testing.with.alexandra.marin/

Rob Gibbens from Xamarin University also has a great blog post on this: http://arteksoftware.com/bdd-tests-with-xamarin-uitest-and-specflow/

We use this in anger at work - we run a small suite of UI tests for every pull request and a huge nightly run covering off everything on a range of devices. Every single test is written as a set of SpecFlow scenarios using the screen object pattern. We test locally on a range of physical devices as we need to connect to in house servers but will occasionally use Test Cloud to research an issue that only occurs on one particular device.

Answer (score 1):

its for test your app on any device 
test Views , functionality and ...
instead of install your app on many android or IOS device and test your app , create an aotomation for it 
there is many Frame for But I think the best of them is [Appium](http://appium.io/)
and you can use something like [this](http://testdroid.com/products/testdroid-cloud) for test any andorid device with any version ...
actually appium work such as a robot ...

Comment: Thanks Mohamaad. 
But i am new in BDD. 
Can you please give me any example How can i start from Scratched and 
Can i create my own Framework.

Comment: @manoj start working with appium , search on youtube there is many toturial video , but i can explane it : first you connect your phone and connect to it with adb , and start appium server then you should aoutomate on your phone with appium , you can use any language but i use ,net API .

Comment: If i want to write my own Automation test in C#, Can i write?

Comment: yes , why not ? actually you connect to appium server in your localcomputer with .net API

Answer (score 0):

Automated test framework allows some testing procedure that minimize the repeated tasks. The test case is executed on screen with different set of data. BDD is a technique in which the sample data set are already generated and used during development to make sure that implementation is correct.